# How to pass incoming model to attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, backend

So I would like to authorize a user for a specific item. So for example:

```
      [Authorize(Roles = ItemAccess.AuthorizedRoleList(AccessType.Write,id))]
      public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
      {
      }
```

But I cannot access the id Property. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom authorize attribute where you will have access to the `id` parameter and can perform any necessary logic:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            return false;
        }

        var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        string id = rd.Values["id"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            // No id was specified => we do not allow access
            return false;
        }

        string roles = ItemAccess.AuthorizedRoleList(AccessType.Write, id);
        return httpContext.User.IsInRole(roles))
    }
}
```

and finally decorate your controller action with this custom attribute:

```
  [MyAuthorize]
  public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
  {
  }
```